# Flutter: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.2) in Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

runing my app in debug, is not given me any issue but if run it on release it keep crashing only on `Android` but `iOS` is working perfectly...

after sign in with email and password it will just crash..

adding crashlytics make me to understand that is coming from `Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.2)` but the code is working perfect in iOS.

here is the function i call that crash.

```
Future<bool> signAuth(
    {String? name,
    String? email,
    String? password,
    String? gender,
    String? university,
    String? refCode,
    String? username,
    String? type,
    BuildContext? context}) async {
  try {
    final user = (await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email!, password: password!))
        .user;
    await user!.sendEmailVerification();
    await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      'id': user.uid,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'name': name,
      'refCode': refCode,
      'university': university,
      'password': password.hashCode,
      'gender': gender,
      'type': type
    });
    return true;
```

is authenticating but not storing the datas in firestore. [image: auth]

but not storing the remaining datas to firestore.

Error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone have issues that deals with `Internal error in Cloud Firestore` in general this will solve the problem

Step 1:

Create the of this list of file in your `yourProjectName/Android/app` Note: (if exit not need of creating it again)

```
proguard-android.txt 
proguard-rules.pro
```

Step 2:

copy below config:

```
-keep class io.grpc.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Paste the code inside the Step 1 two files created or exist.

Step 3:
(then go to ==> myProjectName/Android/app/build.gradle see them by adding this line)

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

//add only the below code
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' //Add this to it.......
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, any other solution?

Comment: it should work.. it works for me..

Comment: @JeanEric open a question so that i can see your error... did you add crashalystic to your app ?

Comment: It worked. All i had to do was to clean project and then invalidate cache and restart the project then build

Comment: @JeanEric okay.. yea you have to clean the project